# ipad movie paused rather play when page is loaded

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a movie that loads fine and plays fine but it plays as soon as the page loads. I would like it to load in a paused state requiring the user to hen press play to watch.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iobserve1" ofType:@"mov"];
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(60, 44, 900, 656);  // player's frame must match parent's
[self.movieView addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
[moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
[moviePlayerController pause];
}
```

The pause on the last line does not seem to do anything. Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code blurb you've written above in viewwillappear. 
Then add play at the end like so:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear: (BOOL) animated {
  NSString *moviePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"iobserve1" ofType:@"mov"];
  NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:moviePath];
  moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];
  moviePlayerController.view.frame = CGRectMake(60, 44, 900, 656);  // player's frame must match parent's
  [self.movieView addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
  moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
  [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
  [moviePlayerController play];
 }
```

at the end of it.

In a viewdidappear do a

```
  -(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [moviePlayerController pause];
  }
```

Remember to remove code from viewDidLoad

Comment: That is great - thank you so much. Just out of interest there is a very slight movement at the start and then it stops. Any idea why this might be? A very small point but just interested. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try setting the `MPMoviePlayerController` property `shouldAutoplay` to `NO`.

Add the following line before your `prepareToPlay` call;

```
moviewPlayerController.shouldAutoplay = NO;
```

---

From the reference:

```
shouldAutoplay
```

A Boolean that indicates whether a movie should begin playback automatically.

```
@property (nonatomic) BOOL shouldAutoplay
```

***Discussion***

> The default value of this property is YES. This property determines
>   whether the playback of network-based content begins automatically
>   when there is enough buffered data to ensure uninterrupted playback.

Availability
Available in iOS 3.2 and later.
Declared In

Comment: That is great too - it stops the initial movement. Thanks to you both.